# Resize Vectors Julia

Tags: arrays, vector, julia

So I am trying to re-size vector of vectors in Julia like this:

```
A = [Vector{Any}() for i in 1:6]
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
for tt = 1:6
    a+=1
    resize!(A[tt], a)
    for rr = 1:a
        b+=1
        resize!(A[tt][rr], b)
        for tt2 = 1:b
            resize!(A[tt][rr][tt2], b)
        end
    end
end
```

I am getting this error:

> UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
>
> Stacktrace:  [1] getindex(::Array{Any,1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:549 
>   [2] macro expansion at ./In[70]:7 [inlined]  [3] anonymous at
>   ./:?

Any help please?

Comment: Please don't post the same questions on multiple forums, it duplicates the work of volunteers taking time answering them, see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/vector-re-size/13733, https://discourse.julialang.org/t/vector-of-vectors/13748/2

Comment: I am sorry about that. There was no reply to that post on discourse, so I had to post it here, since there are many members on Stackoverflow who are very active here but not that much on discourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

*Problem 1*. `resize!` changes the size of the vector but does not initialize its elements. If vector has element type `Any` then the entries will be `#undef` which means uninitialized. You have to initialize them first before accessing.

Here is an example:

```
julia> A = Any[]
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> resize!(A, 1)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 #undef

julia> resize!(A[1], 1) # you get an error
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Array{Any,1}, ::Int64) at .\array.jl:549

julia> A[1] = Any[]
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> A
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[]

julia> resize!(A[1], 1) # now it works
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 #undef

julia> A
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[#undef]
```

*Problem 2*. Your code will not work under Julia 1.0, because you are trying to modify a global variable inside a loop (e.g. `a` in line `a += 1`). Wrap your code inside a function or `let` block to make it not throw an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful.